# express and jade, ignore render errors

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So, express+jade == cool.  No question there.  However, coming from django, i'm missing the failure mode that the django templates used.  In django, if I try to render a variable that doesn't exist, it just ignores it and moves on.  While there are times this is REALLY annoying, most of the time it is not.  As such, when I try to render a variable in jade with express, express complains with a 500 error if that variable doesn't exist/is undefined.

```
500 TypeError: Jade:14 
12. ' // main content, post, login, etc ' 
13. ' - if (data.session.user) ' 
14. ' != partial(\'dash') ' 

Jade:3 
1. '- if (data.session.user)' 
2. ' p #{data.session.user.id}' 
3. ' p #{data.cookie.connect.sid}' Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

I'm just experimenting here, so ignore what i'm trying to print. :)  In summary, is there an easy way to tell jade/express to ignore errors in the template and continue rendering, such as is the behavior in the django template system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible as the renderer throws an error when the evaluation of the javascript fails.

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/jade.js#L197

You can fork the project and add an option to avoid the call to `rethrow` or at least let your render fail better by wrapping `res.render`:

```
app.render = function (res, options) {
  try {
    res.render(options);
  } catch(e) {
    //log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: well shoot.  I don't want to fork it.  I wonder if it would be possible to catch rendering errors and create dummy variables that are null/false and re-render via the catch statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can test for variable existence in Jade:

```
  if typeof(msg) !== 'undefined'
    p #{msg}
```

It's not automatic, but I found this to be a lifesaver.

Comment: this just seems like overkill, a template should not be throwing undefined errors!